# Assigning int ** to an int pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Sry, for the weird question. I have written the following programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int a[2];
    int **vararr = (int **)a;

    int testarr[]= {1, 2 ,3};
    printf("%d %d %d\n", testarr[0], testarr[1], testarr[2]);
    vararr[0] = (int *)testarr;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", testarr[0], testarr[1], testarr[2]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", vararr[0][0], vararr[0][1], vararr[0][2]);
}
```

which returns:

```
1 2 3
32765 2 3
32765 2 3
```

I expected: `vararr[0][0] == 1 && testarr[0] == 1`

If I rerun the Program the 32765 changes by +-2

I really don't see what I did wrong. I couldn't find anything concerning my problem, since i don't really know how to formulate it properly.

Comment: You're casting an `int *` directly to an `int **`. What are you expecting to do here? It seems like you're trying to store an `int *` in an `int`.

Comment: Can you explain your rationale behind `int **vararr = (int **)a;`? Why?

Comment: How do i assign **vararr correctly? I want an array of int pointers

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish? Usually this sort of pointer hijinks is considered a "[code smell](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/)" because it is hard to write, hard to read, and difficult to get right. There are generally better ways to write code.

Comment: You should try to avoid pointer casts whenever possible.  And if you actually dereference a pointer, it should have the correct type for the object it points to.  In this case, you are writing a pointer value into an integer array.  What do you suppose happens if `sizeof(int *)` is greater than `sizeof(int)`?  Undefined behavior.  You'll corrupt your runtime environment.  Don't do it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes

Comment: You say you want an array of `int` pointers, but the compiler won't magically create it for you.  You must first *have* an array of `int` pointers before you can assign its address to a pointer variable.

Comment: @Chelz Do you want `vararr` to be a pointer to an array of `int` or do you want an array of pointers to `int`? These are very different types and it isn't clear to me which you are trying to achieve. Please edit the question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reinterpret a pointer to integer (decayed from an array) as a pointer to pointer to integer. The pointed types (int and pointer to int) are not pointer-interconvertible, so when you attempt to access the pointed object by indirecting through the reinterpreted pointer, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I want an array of int pointers

You can declare an array of int pointers like this:

```
int* ptr_arr[] {testarr};
```

This is an array of one element. The element is a pointer to int. It points to the first element of `testarr`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what i want. What would be the correct way, if I wanted to use int **ptr_arr?

Comment: @Chelz `T[]` is implicitly convertible to `T*` so `int*[]` is implicitly convertible to `int**`. You can use `ptr_arr` wherever you would need an `int**`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i wanted to ask, how to initialize the array, using `int ** ptr_arr`.

Comment: @Chelz What kind of array are you trying to initialise with `int**`?

Comment: @Chelz Please see my last comment in the question section. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I wanted to know if I can initialize the array if int pointers with a different syntax, using `int **`

Comment: @Chelz See my answer for how to create an array of int pointers. You cannot store `int**` within an array of int pointers. You can store `int**` objects within an array of pointers to pointers to int.

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 3):

`int **vararr = (int **)a;` is an invalid conversion since the types are not compatible.

A pointer to pointer:

- is not an array
- is not a 2D array
- cannot point at an array
- cannot point at a 2D array
- may be used to point at the *first element of an array of pointers*

Meaning that unless you have an `int* array[n]` laying around somewhere, there is no sense in using an `int**`.

Replace the `int**` with a `int*` and everything will work fine.

Comment: `may be used to point at the first element of an array of pointers` More generally though, it may be used to point to any pointer (of appropriate type), whether it is the first element of an array, the second element, or not in an array at all.